# What if you already know the tree structure? Are there an alternative to composite pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I'm dealing with an API (not an OO kind of thing) that has a tree like structure. Every node in a tree has a specific handler that you need to specify when creating it's children.

The idea is to create a wrapper classes around the objects of the tree to make it integrate easier into the future projects.

The question is how to do that? If you already know the tree structure in advance, composite pattern would not work that well. Are there any alternatives? How would you design the wrapper classes around a large, but fixed number of tree objects?

Is it just list-all-child-nodes-as-fields-in-parent-class kind of thing?

Comment: An example would make the question easier to understand.

Comment: Imagine this data structure [link](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-4k3Gz-6_V-I/Tb53lXbtuAI/AAAAAAAAAHg/VzGK8sys78g/s1600/800px-Tree-data-structure.svg.png) to be an API I need to call. Every node has it's own set of properties, is dependent on the parent node and represents a part of the functionality from the API.

The question is how to design my classes around those objects?

Comment: so, did you finally found a way to avoid composite mode? :)

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the [tree](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-4k3Gz-6_V-I/Tb53lXbtuAI/AAAAAAAAAHg/VzGK8sys78g/s1600/800px-Tree-data-structure.svg.png) it is balanced so you can use binary search to quickly get to the last node  you need for this specific project.

I assume they are in some kind of a linked list structure so you build a contractor that gets the parent node (And obviously all of the connections up to the needed point since it should  recursively climb the tree from the source to the parent node).

It is some what similar to [expression trees](http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd300/Topic/ExpressionTree/index.html).

Comment: The tree I linked to was just an example. The question is not regarding the tree itself. Objects in API that I'm trying to utilize have a tree like structure.

Think of this API as a configuration you have to build up. This configuration can hold a bunch of things but then again it can only hold a few of them. They are, of course, linked to each other in tree like fashion.

My code has to wrap around that API so that it could work in a nice, understandable, OO way. My question is regarding how to design that code.

I hope you understand....

Comment: Sorry, Really hard to understand what you need. What stops you from using them in a OO way?

Comment: Nothing really. I was looking for possible design solutions. The only way I can think of is to create one class per tree node and link them together through class fields. I was wondering if there's another way?

so the question would be. If you had a tree - any tree of fixed size, how would you represent it and use it in your code in a meaningful way?

Comment: Just what you said. Occam's razor etc'